# Run python function from terminal

Tags: python, macos, bash, terminal

I have a nice python class and I need to instantiate the class, and then I need to run a specific function in that class. Basically, we are using a language like PHP to run shell commands. Here is my python class (lighting.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from phue import Bridge
from pprint import pprint
import time
import logging;logging.basicConfig()

class OfficeLights(object):

    #Basically Python's constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
        self.username = 'xxxxx'
        self.lightInterface = Bridge(self.ip, self.username) 
        self.lightInterface.connect()
        self.lightInterface.get_api()
        self.lightInterface.create_group('Office', [1,2,3,4])
        self.cycles = 15 
        self.period = 1 
        self.evvDev = 'http://dev.google.com'
        self.evvStage = 'http://staging.google.com'

    #List all the lights available to play with
    def listLights(self):
        lights = self.lightInterface.lights

        for l in lights:
            print(l.name)

    #Generic strobe function
    def strobe(self, hue, cycles):
        for x in range(0, cycles):
            self.lightInterface.set_group(1, 'on', True)
            self.lightInterface.set_group(1, 'hue', hue)
            self.lightInterface.set_group(1, 'bri', 254)
            time.sleep(self.period)
            self.lightInterface.set_group(1, 'on', False)
            time.sleep(self.period)

    #Flashing funtions, to be executed on actions
    def flashRed(self):
        self.strobe(0, self.cycles)

    def flashGreen(self):
        self.strobe(25500, self.cycles)

    def flashPurple(self):
        self.strobe(46920, self.cycles)

    def flashPink(self):
        self.strobe(56100, self.cycles)

    #Check if a website is up/down based on https status headers
    def is_website_online(self, host):
        import httplib2
        h = httplib2.Http()
        resp = h.request(host, 'HEAD')
        return int(resp[0]['status']) < 400

    #Check EVV sites for up/down
    def check_evv_sites(self):
        if(self.is_website_online(self.evvDev) is not True):
            self.flashRed()
        if(self.is_website_online(self.evvStage) is not True):
            self.flashRed()
        else:
            self.flashGreen()
```

I am trying to run the command from terminal but I only ever get the error that 'OfficeLights is not defined'? Not sure what else I need to do?

```
python -c 'import lighting; lights = OfficeLights(); lights.flashPurple();'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test sample:

```
└> cat hello.py
class Hello:
    def hello(self):
        print "hello"

└> python -c 'from hello import Hello; h= Hello(); h.hello()'
hello

└> python -c 'import hello; h= hello.Hello(); h.hello()'
hello
```

you can choose either `import mypackage.mymodule` or `from mypackage.mymodule import myclass`

```
python -c 'from lighting import OfficeLights; lights = OfficeLights(); lights.flashPurple();'
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not consider at all to import the class itself, works very well now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference the module imported or use the from method listed in the previous answer.

```
python -c 'import lighting; lights = lighting.OfficeLights(); lights.flashPurple();'
```

Additionally, the module needs to be in your project path, or the command needs to be issued from the same directory containing the module.